# 3blue1brown Playing Pool with Pi Variation.

Tags: physics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I often like doing variations of math puzzles and riddles. For this one though, it's extremely hard for me to find a simulation runner to solve this variation, and this variation also is a lot tougher.

Here's a quick refresher of the original problem, as described in 3blue1brown's YouTube video ["The most unexpected answer to a counting puzzle"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEfHFsfGXjs).

> The problem includes two sliding blocks and a wall, the second block is coming at the other block at some velocity, while the second one starts out stationary. This is a overly idealistic problem where the floor is friction-less and all collisions are perfectly elastic. When the second block has a mass of a power of 100 in kilograms and the second block is 1 kg, a neat fact popped out that the total number of collisions has digits of $\pi$. (ex. if the second block is 100kg the number of collisions is 31)

My variation is that instead of 2 blocks, there are 3 blocks, each heavier than the other. When I tried doing this with a program that let's you run lots of physics simulations, having each block having a power of 100, it just, broke. So then I had a hypothesis, if the resulting number of collisions for the original puzzle had digits of $\pi$ (pi) , then the second one *should* have the digits of $\tau$ (tau, aka $2\pi$)

I hope one of you guys reading this post can help me find out the number of collisions, thanks.

Comment: Brother, is this a physics or math question ?

Comment: It's kind of both, since it involves some mathy stuff

Comment: If the 3 blocks are arranged linearly, the number of collisions the middle gets into reduces, but I have no reason why (which means that this just a small guess I make).

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean my reduces, can you explain?

Comment: You should explain the original problem explicitely in the question instead of linking a video.

Comment: Sure, hold on a minute

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by reduces, can you explain? - just refer the word meaning of reduces.

Comment: I am only making a guess....

Comment: Taking a case where the 3 blocks have equal masses and are equidistant from each other, all blocks get an equal number of hits, I guess....

Comment: We're looking for when the second and third mass both have a power of 100

Comment: Yup, I only spoke of what I know.

Comment: The lightest of the three will earn the maximum number of collisions, but everything (the number of collisions, its afterward motion,etc)are decided by the masses of the other two .

Comment: Again a guess! Not to be believed !

Comment: It's actually the middle block that experticences the most collisions

Comment: In the original problem, if you have both blocks the same mass, you get $3$ collisions, where $3$ is the first digit of $\pi$. In the $3$ block problem, if all three blocks are the same mass, it is quite easy to see that there are $5$ collisions, but $5$ is not the first digit of $\tau$.

Comment: That's a very good point there.

Comment: It's actually the middle block that experticences the most collisions  - Thanks for letting me know.....

Comment: What are the initial velocities of the three blocks?